# What will be called first?

Tags: netty

I have this piece of code in my program:

```
ChannelFuture future = channel.write(msg);  
future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {                     
                System.out.println("wrote ");
           }
});
System.out.println("done ");
```

What will be executed first: System.out.println("wrote "); or System.out.println("done "); ?

Comment: Did you try? Why do you care at all?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how fast the write is. If the write was complete before you add the listener it will first print "wrote ". Otherwise "done "...